For compact Hausdorff spaces, is countable pseudocharacter equivalent to first countable?
Let $X$ be a compact $T_2$ space. Is $X$ first countable if, and only if, $X$ has countable pseudocharacter?
Note: I have already proven that every $T_1$ first countable space has countable pseudocharacter.
I also wonder if $T_2$ hypothesis can be weakened to $T_1$ or if compact hypothesis can be weakened to locally compact.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Yes it is equivalent (for Hausdorff spaces at least). This is known. Check Handbook of set-theoretic topology. A lot of cardinal functions are equal for compact Hausdorff spaces.

More precisely, $\psi(X) = \chi(X)$ for compact Hausdorff $X$ (notation as in above book)

There are examples of spaces with $\chi(X) > \psi(X) = \aleph_0$ and $X$ is compact $T_1$ space, for example the one-point compactification of the rationals.

According to this comment the same proof applies to show a locally compact Hausdorff space with countable pseudocharacter is first countable i.e. $\psi(X) = \chi(X) = \aleph_0$.

Thank you very much for all the help, sir. Have a great day.
